# scraping rotten tomatoes 12 years a slave movie

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, tagname

I'm trying to scrape the number of audience ratings from this page
https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/12_years_a_slave (which is 100,000+) using python selenium.
I tried all kinds of selenium locators but every time i get NoSuchElementException: error.
Here is my code :

```py
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('path.exe')
url = 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/12_years_a_slave'
driver.get(url)
    
def scrape_dom(element):
    shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return 
        arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
    retuen shadow_root

host = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('score-board')
root_1 = scrape_dom(host)
views = root_1.find_element_by_link_text(
        '/m/12_years_a_slave/reviews?type=user&amp;intcmp=rt-' + \
        'scorecard_audience-score-reviews')
```

I also tried xpath , css_selector but always error.may you tell me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

A simple CSS selector work here.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/12_years_a_slave'
driver.get(url)

print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[slot=audience-count]').text)
```

I get `100,000+ Ratings` printed out to my console.

Comment: But how it worked without getting access to the shadow root? may you tell me please@Justin Ezequiel .

Comment: I've never needed the `.shadowRoot` before so I do not understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

See if this xpath works:-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@data-qa='audience-rating-count']").text
```

Comment: Yes it worked, but i'm confused because i though i have to access the shadow DOM always @itronic1990

Comment: I have never used shadow root in my xpaths till now

Answer (score 0):

You don't need selenium. You can use `requests` and `bs4`. Also, you can use a faster css class selector, rather than slower attribute selector given in other answers so far.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/12_years_a_slave')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
soup.select_one('.scoreboard__link--audience').text
```

Comment: Thank you @QHarr , those shadow doms confused me a lot.